# Why there's a finite $\Gamma '$ such that $\Gamma ' \vDash \varphi$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose $\Gamma$ is an infinite set of formulas in FOL. It is given that for a structure, $M$: If $\Gamma$ is satisfiable in $M$ then $\varphi$ is valid in $M$.

Why is it true that there's some finite $\Gamma ' \subset \Gamma$, such that $\Gamma ' \vDash \varphi$?

It reminds the compactness theorem in a way, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: $\Gamma$ and non-$\phi$ has no model, i.e. (by completeness theorem) you can derive a contradiction from a finite subset of $\Gamma$ and from non-$\phi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a consequence of compactness. HINT: If $\Gamma\models\varphi$, then $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is unsatisfiable. What does the *contrapositive* of the Compactness Theorem tell you about a theory which is unsatisfiable?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see your answer.

Comment: @Leo163 No reason to apologize, simultaneous answers happen! (I upvoted yours btw.)

Comment: Oh nice. By the compactness theorem there's some finite $\Gamma ' \cup \{\lnot \varphi\}$ which isn't satisfiable which implies $\Gamma '\vDash \varphi$

Answer (score 2):

From the Compactness Theorem, if there is no finite $\Gamma'\subset\Gamma$ with $\Gamma'\models\varphi$, then $\Gamma\not\models\varphi$. From your hypothesis, it follows that $\Gamma$ cannot be satisfiable. But then, again by Compactness, there is a finite $\Gamma'\subset\Gamma$ with $\Gamma'\vdash\perp$, which means $\Gamma'\models\varphi$.

If otherwise there is a finite $\Gamma'$ as you ask, the thesis follows immediately.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Gamma'\vdash\perp$?